# How can create a new string from an original string replacing all non-instances of a character

Tags: string, python-3.x

So Let's say I have a random string "Mississippi"

I want to create a new string from "Mississippi" but replacing all the non-instances of a particular character.

For example if we use the letter "S". In the new string, I want to keep all the S's in "MISSISSIPPI" and replace all the other letters with a "_".

I know how to do the reverse:

```
word = "MISSISSIPPI"
word2 = word.replace("S", "_")
print(word2)
```

word2 gives me MI__I__IPPI

but I can't figure out how to get word2 to be __SS_SS____

(The classic Hangman Game)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the [sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) method of Python strings with a regular expression for symbolizing a NOT character set such as

```
import re
line = re.sub(r"[^S]", "_", line)
```

This replaces any non S character with the desired character.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `str.maketrans()` and `str.translate()` but it would be easier with regular expressions.  The trick is you need to insert your string of valid characters into the regular expression programattically:

```
import re

word = "MISSISSIPPI"

show = 'S'  # augment as the game progresses

print(re.sub(r"[^{}]".format(show), "_", word))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to map a function across the string:

```
>>> ''.join(map(lambda w: '_' if w != 'S' else 'S', 'MISSISSIPPI'))
'__SS_SS____'
```